# Redis Config Files - Config Write

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

- I have 5 redis server
- 2 of them run redis both Master and Slave roles ( looks like redis.conf is not setup manually but via some sort of process cause it has the following line at the bottom:   Generated by CONFIG REWRITE )
- From time to time I can see Master and Slave switch roles automatically - no human intervention
- 3 of them run redis sentinel

**Question 1:** I need to replicate this setup on a 5 different systems but I don’t know how is that “Generated by CONFIG REWRITE” portion setup.  Where and how is this automation setup?

**Question 2:** Why is that /etc/redis/ has a 6329.conf file? I thought redis setup is redis.conf...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Config Rewrites are all caused by Redis Sentinel. The 3 sentinels you have monitor the master and in the event that enough sentinels think the master is down, they will force a failover by promoting an existing slave to the new master, then will reconfigure all other hosts to be a slave of the new master. You can read more about Redis Sentinel, including how to set it up for common scenarios, ([docs page](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel), [examples section](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#example-sentinel-deployments)).

For the 6329.conf file, you can name the config files however you want, but however you start your redis server has to reference the non-default file name. Here's the usage example from the `--help` option to `redis-server`:

```
Usage: ./redis-server [/path/to/redis.conf] [options]
```